Update embedded google sheet faster than 5 minutes
I have embedded google sheets in a web page. The google sheets are updating frequently but the update is reflected in my web page after 5 minutes. How can I update quicker? Runtime or at least every 10 seconds?
I have 8 sheets embedded in 8 I frames. So far I have tried bypass caching but for some reason this is also not working.
    </script>
    function refreshAllIframes() {
        const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
        iframes.forEach(iframe => {
        const url = new URL(iframe.src);
        url.searchParams.set('timestamp', new Date().getTime()); 
        iframe.src=url.toString();
    
        });
      } 
       setInterval(refreshAllIframes, 10000);
    </script>
    
    
    <iframe id="screen1" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTb_FLqllCprfiONXzn0qYD7N8KF7WBZuaH0sDANthjZBrwdVSwiz2KPFu7M5VHluxZ3io3sgr1_wnh/pubhtml?gid=0&headers=false&chrome=false&range=B:H&timestamp=<current-time>" width="100%" height="100%">
    </iframe>

7 more iframes like this.

Is automatic updates  "on"? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?

Are you open to using Google App Script (GAS)? If so, it would be faster.
